# Import multiple HTML files into GitHub as Markdown

Tags: html, import, markdown

I have a rather big tree of HTML files that I would like to import into a GitHub repo as markdown files. Is this possible? Is there a built-in converter or are there good third-party tools for this?

Heard about Pandoc. Seems to be the best option I found so far. True?

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```html
and here your code
```

so Markdown will see the code as html

your code needs to be around three of theses: ``
and with Html write in front of it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).